# Demoted after given away reputation points

Tags: discussion, reputation

Why can I no longer perform tasks on this forum that I was able to before. I understand I gave away the reputation, but I still got the “experience”. What’s the deal?

Comment: How does the system know you have the experience? What metric do you expect it should use to measure that?

Comment: You’d think it’d keep track of the difference between giving away points and never having them in the first place.

Comment: Then of what cost is there to you in giving them away? You're paying for the bounty not getting it for free

Comment: I understand the confusion; there's a difference between decreasing the number by your name and giving up privileges that are gained after reaching certain rep levels.  We don't suddenly trust you less because you gave a bounty.  But we do trust you less if you get a lot of downvotes, so it couldn't just track a "high-water mark".  I think there's a post on MSE about this somewhere.

Comment: This is why I never give away bounties (at this point)... I'm too afraid of losing reputation. :P

Comment: @monic https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4780/166155